# SQL SUM BETWEEN TWO COUNT RESULT

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 

  [Soldtopt],

  [tradingname],
  [DlvDate],
  SUM(try_cast(Netvalue as float)) as Netvalue,  
 count(distinct SDDoc)   as Salesdoc ,
 count(distinct case when  Netvalue = '0' then 1 else null end) as ZeroValue ,

 sum (count(distinct SDDoc)) , (count(distinct case when  Netvalue = '0' then 1 else null end)) As result

FROM [FOC].[dbo].[foc]


GROUP by Soldtopt,tradingname,DlvDate  ORDER BY  count (distinct SDDoc) DESC;
```

is this correct to way to bring the `sum(
sum (count(distinct SDDoc)) , (count(distinct case when  Netvalue = '0' then 1 else null end)) As result)`
? or i am getting error "

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
>   Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."
>   [enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1LGz.jpg hi in this result should be like 2,2,0,1 where as result shows like 35,35,35,35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUM OVER()`

```
SELECT [Soldtopt],
       [tradingname],
       [DlvDate],
       Sum(try_cast(Netvalue as float)) AS Netvalue,
       Count(DISTINCT SDDoc)   AS Salesdoc,
       Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Netvalue = '0' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ZeroValue, -- will always return 1
       Sum (Count(DISTINCT SDDoc))OVER(),
       Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Netvalue = '0' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS result -- will always return 1
FROM   [FOC].[dbo].[foc]
GROUP  BY Soldtopt,
          tradingname,
          DlvDate
ORDER  BY Count (DISTINCT SDDoc) DESC;
```

Also this `Count` aggregate will always return `1`

```
Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Netvalue = '0' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

Adding sample data and expected result can fix the logical mistakes in your query

Comment: hi thanks for your speed reply. what if  i need sum like this,Sum (Count(DISTINCT SDDoc))OVER(),
       Count(DISTINCT where  Netvalue = '0' ) AS result

Comment: @user6827927 - still same logic `sum(count(case when Netvalue = '0' then 1 end)) over()`

Comment: Hello Prdp . attached my current and expected result.

Comment: solved.count(distinct SDDoc) - count(distinct case when  Netvalue = '0' then 1 else null end) As Result

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY  count (distinct SDDoc) DESC;
```

This will sort the data according to the number of col whose index is the value returned by the count function.

```
sum (count(distinct SDDoc))
```

This isn't a valid statement.

```
 count(distinct case when  Netvalue = '0' then 1 else null end)
```

Also try using a subquery in this count.

Answer (score 0):

solved.count(distinct SDDoc) - count(distinct case when  Netvalue = '0' then 1 else null end) As Result